# Spring Integration: Recursive Flow?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm new to Spring/Spring Integration and am having trouble understanding how to correctly implement a flow that with allow for a variable number of outbound gateway calls.

**The Problem:** Given a customer-id, I make one outbound gateway call to get a list of related customers. For each of those related customers, I then need to make another outbound gateway call.

**My Initial Approach:** After the first service call, I fill a Queue with the received related-customer-ids, call a helper method to poll the queue, then continue the flow by calling the outbound gateway again to execute the next request (only if there is a customer left). After the response is received, the gateway then makes a call to the same helper method which repeats the process.

If the queue is empty, a header is used to route the flow towards a logAndReply within the helper method (see below for code).

```
private IntegrationFlow helperMethod()
{
    return flow -> flow

        .transform(payload -> {
            currentCust = info.poll();
            return payload;
        })

        //check if there is another related-customer to process
        .handle(
                (payload, headers) -> MessageBuilder
                        .withPayload(payload)
                        .copyHeaders(headers)
                        .setHeader("relatedCustomerLeft", (null == currentCust ? Boolean.FALSE : Boolean.TRUE))
                        .build()
        )
        .route(("headers['relatedCustomerLeft']"), route -> route

                //if no more related-customers, end the flow
                .subFlowMapping(Boolean.FALSE,
                        subFlow -> subFlow
                            .logAndReply(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, "end of base case")
                )
                //if there is a related customer, call the gateway
                .subFlowMapping(Boolean.TRUE,
                        subGateway()
                )
        );
}
```

Here, subGateway() just returns another IntegrationFlow which handles the outbound service call. This logic seems to work when I remove the recursive calls. However, including the recursive calls causes a stack overflow error on startup. The log just shows "Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol" over and over until the stack overflow occurs.

> "Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'getFlow' defined in file
>   [GetFlow.class]:
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.StackOverflowError"

My questions are

1. Why would the stack overflow occur?
2. Is recursion even possible the way I'm trying to use it? How do I implement it correctly?
3. Is there a better way to go about making a variable number of gateway calls? Any examples?

As I said I'm still new so any tips or resources would also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't show how you create that recursion, secondly it is not clear why would one need a recursion in your use-case at all.

It sounds like you need an `enrich()` "to get a list of related customers".
Then you need `split()` against that returned list of customers to call a service for each of them. And seems for me that's all! No any recursion needed.

I also would consider to have a `filter()` before `split()` to be sure that the list is not empty. Or `route()` as you have already...

But still not clear where would that recursion pop up...

Comment: The recursion is a result of subGateway() calling helperMethod() after it has executed the outbound service call. My idea was to save the response of each service call to build a final response message after all related customers were accounted for. I'll try your recommendation though instead. Thanks!

Comment: It's not good to save result somewhere in a shared place: some other process may get access to data not related to it. It is really good to save intermediate data in the message headers.